# How to overwrite a rewrite_tag in fluent-bit

Tags: filter, fluent-bit, fluent-bit-rewrite-tag

In my scenario, I'm using a fluent-bit (*version 1.6.1*) filter to identify a particular log pattern and tag (*from.solr.out*) it.

```
[FILTER]
    Name          rewrite_tag
    Match         test_tag
    Rule          $msg "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*$"  from.solr.out false
    Emitter_Name  re_emitted
```

Then I modify the record to add a field like below

```
[FILTER]
    Name record_modifier
    Match from.solr.out
    Record aid 53
```

Now I need to give a new tag (*format.logging*) to that modified record which I tried with below code snippet and it doesn't work.

```
[FILTER]
    Name          rewrite_tag
    Match         from.solr.out
    Rule          $from.solr.out "^.*$"  format.logging false
    Emitter_Name  re_emitted_indexing
```

- What is wrong with that approach?
- Is there any better approach/filter to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out how to get the result that I expected.

```
...
[2020/10/22 12:49:07] [ info] [sp] stream processor started
[0] format.logging: [1603351147.631883694, {"msg"=>"2020-10-16 09:29:03.968 WARN  ...
```

I thought the original message that comes with the tag *$msg* is disappearing after adding the new tag (*from.solr.out*). Because in my second filter, I'm adding a record to the second tag (*from.solr.out*) not the initial tag (*$msg*).

Then in the last filter, I was trying to create a new tag (*format.logging*) by using the second tag (*from.solr.out*). That's where things have gone wrong. Instead of using the second tag, I tried to use the first tag (*$msg*) here. Then I got all the changes I needed as the output.

Changes I was expecting were;

- Filter the input message to identify some logs
- Add a field to the identified messages
- Tag the modified message

The final change I've done is

```
[FILTER]
    Name          rewrite_tag
    Match         from.solr.out
    Rule          $msg "^.*$"  format.logging false
    Emitter_Name  re_emitted_indexing
```